# How to draw the images of these six functions in six different coordinate systems at one time as required?

Tags: plotting, homework

The six functions are as follows:

```
f1[x_] := x Log[x]
f2[x_] := x/Log[x]
f3[x_] := Log[x]/x
f4[x_] := x E^x
f5[x_] := x/E^x
f6[x_] := E^x/x
```

It is required to draw six function images in the six coordinate systems, and each image should identify the position and coordinate value of the minimum or maximum value point. From the minimum or maximum value point, use the dotted line to make the vertical line of the x-axis and y-axis, and also identify the intersection value of the x-axis and y-axis. See the picture for the specific form:

[image]

Similar to this effect: six coordinate systems and six function images：

[image]

like this：

[image]

Comment: My observation is that you have asked many questions of varying complexity  in recent weeks. You should be able to put labels and lines on a curve without further help.

Comment: Not sure how clear it is to the others, but for me it's not clear at all what you mean by coordinate systems. In principle, we can take two axes, and plot a circle and `f1[x]` etc and show the desired points.

Comment: The picture shows three different tangents of three coordinate systems. I have a similar effect here, drawing six different function images in six separate coordinate systems.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Edit:** plotting all the six functions together results in

> [image: sixplots]

Code for the above is provided below: note that the commented-out parts are such that points' coordinates do not duplicate.

```
f1[x_] := x Log[x]
minmax1 = Transpose[{#, f1 /@ #}] &@(x /. Solve[f1'[x] == 0, x]);
p1 = Plot[f1[x], {x, -2, 5},
   PlotRange -> {{-2, 5}, {-1, 3.5}},
   Epilog -> {
     PointSize[Large],
     Red,
     Point[minmax1],
     Style[Text[Flatten[minmax1], Offset[{0, -30}, Flatten[minmax1]]],
       FontSize -> 14],
     Lighter[Gray], Dashed,
     Line[{{Flatten[minmax1][[1]], 0}, {Flatten[minmax1][[1]], 
        f1[x] /. x -> Flatten[minmax1][[1]]}, {0, 
        f1[x] /. x -> Flatten[minmax1][[1]]}}],
     Lighter[Red],
     Style[
      Text[Flatten[minmax1][[1]], 
       Offset[{Flatten[minmax1][[1]], 20}, {Flatten[minmax1][[1]], 
         0}]], FontSize -> 14], 
     Style[Text[Flatten[minmax1][[2]], 
       Offset[{-30, Flatten[minmax1][[2]]}, {0, 
         Flatten[minmax1][[2]]}]], FontSize -> 14]
     },
   ImageSize -> Full
   ];
f2[x_] := x/Log[x]
minmax2 = Transpose[{#, f2 /@ #}] &@(x /. Solve[f2'[x] == 0, x]);
p2 = Plot[f2[x], {x, -2, 5}, PlotStyle -> Darker[Green],
   PlotRange -> {{-2, 5}, {-1, 3.5}},
   Epilog -> {
     PointSize[Large],
     Red,
     Point[minmax2],
     Style[Text[Flatten[minmax2], Offset[{0, 10}, Flatten[minmax2]]], 
      FontSize -> 14],
     Lighter[Gray], Dashed,
     Line[{{Flatten[minmax2][[1]], 0}, {Flatten[minmax2][[1]], 
        f2[x] /. x -> Flatten[minmax2][[1]]}, {0, 
        f2[x] /. x -> Flatten[minmax2][[1]]}}],
     Lighter[Red],
     Style[
      Text[Flatten[minmax2][[1]], 
       Offset[{Flatten[minmax2][[1]], -10}, {Flatten[minmax2][[1]], 
         0}]], FontSize -> 14], 
     Style[Text[Flatten[minmax2][[2]], 
       Offset[{-10, Flatten[minmax2][[2]]}, {0, 
         Flatten[minmax2][[2]]}]], FontSize -> 14]
     },
   ImageSize -> Full
   ];
f3[x_] := Log[x]/x
minmax3 = Transpose[{#, f3 /@ #}] &@(x /. Solve[f3'[x] == 0, x]);
p3 = Plot[f3[x], {x, -2, 5}, PlotStyle -> Orange,
   PlotRange -> {{-2, 5}, {-1, 3.5}},
   Epilog -> {
     PointSize[Large],
     Red,
     Point[minmax3],
     Style[Text[Flatten[minmax3], Offset[{0, 20}, Flatten[minmax3]]], 
      FontSize -> 14],
     Lighter[Gray],
     Dashed,
     Line[{{Flatten[minmax3][[1]], 0}, {Flatten[minmax3][[1]], 
        f3[x] /. x -> Flatten[minmax3][[1]]}, {0, 
        f3[x] /. x -> Flatten[minmax3][[1]]}}],
     Lighter[Red],
     (*Style[Text[Flatten[minmax3][[1]],Offset[{Flatten[
     minmax3][[1]],-10},{Flatten[minmax3][[1]],0}]],FontSize->14],*)
     Style[Text[Flatten[minmax3][[2]], 
       Offset[{-10, Flatten[minmax3][[2]]}, {0, 
         Flatten[minmax3][[2]]}]], FontSize -> 14]
     },
   ImageSize -> Full
   ];
f4[x_] := x E^x
minmax4 = Transpose[{#, f4 /@ #}] &@(x /. Solve[f4'[x] == 0, x]);
p4 = Plot[f4[x], {x, -2, 5}, PlotStyle -> Black,
   PlotRange -> {{-2, 5}, {-1, 3.5}},
   Epilog -> {
     PointSize[Large],
     Red,
     Point[minmax4],
     Style[Text[Flatten[minmax4], Offset[{0, -30}, Flatten[minmax4]]],
       FontSize -> 14],
     Lighter[Gray],
     Dashed,
     Line[{{Flatten[minmax4][[1]], 0}, {Flatten[minmax4][[1]], 
        f4[x] /. x -> Flatten[minmax4][[1]]}, {0, 
        f4[x] /. x -> Flatten[minmax4][[1]]}}],
     Lighter[Red],
     Style[
      Text[Flatten[minmax4][[1]], 
       Offset[{Flatten[minmax4][[1]], 10}, {Flatten[minmax4][[1]], 
         0}]], FontSize -> 14]
     (*,Style[Text[Flatten[minmax4][[2]],Offset[{20,Flatten[
     minmax4][[2]]},{0,Flatten[minmax4][[2]]}]],FontSize->14]*)
     },
   ImageSize -> Full
   ];
f5[x_] := x/E^x
minmax5 = Transpose[{#, f5 /@ #}] &@(x /. Solve[f5'[x] == 0, x]);
p5 = Plot[f5[x], {x, -2, 5}, PlotStyle -> Darker[Yellow],
   PlotRange -> {{-2, 5}, {-1, 3.5}},
   Epilog -> {
     PointSize[Large],
     Red,
     Point[minmax5],
     Style[Text[Flatten[minmax5], Offset[{0, 30}, Flatten[minmax5]]], 
      FontSize -> 14],
     Lighter[Red], Dashed,
     Line[{{Flatten[minmax5][[1]], 0}, {Flatten[minmax5][[1]], 
        f5[x] /. x -> Flatten[minmax5][[1]]}, {0, 
        f5[x] /. x -> Flatten[minmax5][[1]]}}],
     Lighter[Red],
     Style[
      Text[Flatten[minmax5][[1]], 
       Offset[{Flatten[minmax5][[1]], -40}, {Flatten[minmax5][[1]], 
         0}]], FontSize -> 14]
     (*,Style[Text[Flatten[minmax5][[2]],Offset[{20,Flatten[
     minmax5][[2]]},{0,Flatten[minmax5][[2]]}]],FontSize->14]*)
     },
   ImageSize -> Full
   ];
f6[x_] := E^x/x
minmax6 = Transpose[{#, f6 /@ #}] &@(x /. Solve[f6'[x] == 0, x]);
p6 = Plot[f6[x], {x, -2, 5}, PlotStyle -> Magenta,
   PlotRange -> {{-2, 5}, {-1, 3.5}},
   Epilog -> {
     PointSize[Large],
     Red,
     Point[minmax6],
     Style[Text[Flatten[minmax6], Offset[{0, 40}, Flatten[minmax6]]], 
      FontSize -> 14],
     Lighter[Red], Dashed,
     Line[{{Flatten[minmax6][[1]], 0}, {Flatten[minmax6][[1]], 
        f6[x] /. x -> Flatten[minmax6][[1]]}, {0, 
        f6[x] /. x -> Flatten[minmax6][[1]]}}],
     Lighter[Red]
     (*Style[Text[Flatten[minmax6][[1]],Offset[{Flatten[
     minmax6][[1]],-40},{Flatten[minmax6][[1]],0}]],FontSize->
     14],*)(*Style[Text[Flatten[minmax6][[2]],Offset[{-20,Flatten[
     minmax6][[2]]},{0,Flatten[minmax6][[2]]}]],FontSize->14]*)
     },
   ImageSize -> Full
   ];
Overlay[{p1, p2, p3, p4, p5, p6}]
```

---

---

**Original:**

Not sure what you meant by `draw six function images in the six coordinate systems`. The following can be applied to any of the examples you provided.

Essentially, it's just solving the derivative to be $0$, and then using the output with a bit of formatting on the plot.

```
f1[x_] := x Log[x]
minmax1 = Transpose[{#, f1 /@ #}] &@(x /. Solve[f1'[x] == 0, x]);
Plot[f1[x], {x, -0.1, 3},
 PlotRange -> {{-0.5, 3}, {-1, 1}},
 Epilog -> {
   PointSize[Medium],
   PointSize[Medium],
   Red,
   Point[minmax1],
   Text[Flatten[minmax1], Offset[{0, -30}, Flatten[minmax1]]],
   Lighter[Red], Dashed,
   Line[
    {
     {Flatten[minmax1][[1]], 0}, {Flatten[minmax1][[1]], 
      f1[x] /. x -> Flatten[minmax1][[1]]}, {0, 
      f1[x] /. x -> Flatten[minmax1][[1]]}
     }
    ],
   Text[Flatten[minmax1][[1]], 
    Offset[{Flatten[minmax1][[1]], 20}, {Flatten[minmax1][[1]], 0}]],
   Text[Flatten[minmax1][[2]], 
    Offset[{-30, Flatten[minmax1][[2]]}, {0, Flatten[minmax1][[2]]}]]
   }
 ]
```

> [image: plot]

**Edit:** if the point is to have all the curves and the associated points on one plot, the following is my suggestion:

For `f1[x]`

```
f1[x_] := x Log[x]
minmax1 = Transpose[{#, f1 /@ #}] &@(x /. Solve[f1'[x] == 0, x]);
p1 = Plot[f1[x], {x, -0.1, 5},
   PlotRange -> {{-0.5, 5}, {-1, 3.5}},
   Epilog -> {
     PointSize[Large],
     Red,
     Point[minmax1],
     Text[Flatten[minmax1], Offset[{0, -30}, Flatten[minmax1]]],
     Lighter[Red], Dashed,
     Line[{{Flatten[minmax1][[1]], 0}, {Flatten[minmax1][[1]], 
        f1[x] /. x -> Flatten[minmax1][[1]]}, {0, 
        f1[x] /. x -> Flatten[minmax1][[1]]}}], 
     Text[Flatten[minmax1][[1]], 
      Offset[{Flatten[minmax1][[1]], 20}, {Flatten[minmax1][[1]], 
        0}]], Text[Flatten[minmax1][[2]], 
      Offset[{-30, Flatten[minmax1][[2]]}, {0, Flatten[minmax1][[2]]}]]
     },
   ImageSize -> Full
   ];
```

For `f2[x]`

```
f2[x_] := x/Log[x]
minmax2 = Transpose[{#, f2 /@ #}] &@(x /. Solve[f2'[x] == 0, x]);
p2 = Plot[f2[x], {x, -0.1, 5}, PlotStyle -> Darker[Blue],
   PlotRange -> {{-0.5, 5}, {-1, 3.5}},
   Epilog -> {
     PointSize[Large],
     Red,
     Point[minmax2],
     Text[Flatten[minmax2], Offset[{0, 10}, Flatten[minmax2]]],
     Lighter[Red], Dashed,
     Line[{{Flatten[minmax2][[1]], 0}, {Flatten[minmax2][[1]], 
        f2[x] /. x -> Flatten[minmax2][[1]]}, {0, 
        f2[x] /. x -> Flatten[minmax2][[1]]}}], 
     Text[Flatten[minmax2][[1]], 
      Offset[{Flatten[minmax2][[1]], -10}, {Flatten[minmax2][[1]], 
        0}]], Text[Flatten[minmax2][[2]], 
      Offset[{-10, Flatten[minmax2][[2]]}, {0, Flatten[minmax2][[2]]}]]
     },
   ImageSize -> Full
   ];
```

And now we can [**`Overlay`**](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Overlay.html?v=13.2) them

```
Overlay[{p1, p2}]
```

> [image: twoplots]

Comment: Each function is drawn like this. But I want six different functions to be drawn in six different coordinate systems like this. Finish painting at one time

Comment: draw six function images in the six coordinate systems at one time

Comment: @csn899 sorry but it's still not clear to me. Do you want six different plots, or six curves in one plot?

Comment: Similar effect pictures have been added to the question

Comment: @csn899 the question is still unclear to me. you don't define what you mean by coordinate system. Let a comment under the OP as well. In principle, I showed you how to plot your functions, with their points and the points' coordinate and the dashed lines. Also, showed you how to combine stuff in one plot. But it's not clear what you want to achieve

Comment: Six function images drawn in the same coordinate system are also required. You have given this method.

Comment: Add a picture to the question.like that

Comment: Six pictures, one coordinate system and one function image in each picture